# what does the word virtual users mean in the context of vsts load testing

Tags: azure-pipelines

Here my question currently I'm running some load tests in vsts online. The case is that I run 12 agents with 2000 virtual users what does this mean actually? What I think is that I run a test with 2000 users. The reason is that I generate a massive amount of network traffic to my event hub and 1 request in one event hub message of 3kb. So I want to make sure that I running a max of 2000 users and not 2000 user per agent. The give you an idea I generate a 500MB /sec

thx

Answer (score 0):

It is running a max of 2000 users, not 2000 user per agent.